# Must everyone who uses my program see the ugly code next to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started working on some beginner projects and games to test my abilities.
I found that all I was doing is simply writing a code and seeing the ugly output next to it (in the interactive window). The code works, but that's not how I want a normal user to interfere with it.

I'm looking for a way to display my python program properly to a user. Is there some sort of interface manipulating that I should learn in order to accomplish that? thanks.

[image]

Comment: Console is one of ways to interact with user. Are you searching for [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface)?

Comment: @OlvinRoght, I thought he's looking for GUI and doesn't want to see a console output so 'Tkinter' is good

Comment: @OlvinRoght, I think that this is what I'm looking for, I want the user to press buttons and maybe see images and hear sounds in the output. It's like creating an app that is based on a python script

Comment: @KianRST I searched about Tkinter and I think that it's also an answer to my question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're seeking to build a GUI for your programs.

In several of my early projects, I used the built-in Tkinter module to accomplish what you're suggesting. It may not give you the most modern-looking GUI, but it's nice to use due to it being included with Python by default and the abundance of documentation and tutorials.

There are tons of great videos on YT that walk you through step-by-step on everything from pop-up, dialog-box messages, to full on user-input, menu-laden GUIs. Just search "tkinter tutorials".